# Writing value of FormGroup FormControls in Angular

Tags: formarray

I have an array of FormControls in an inventory application in which I am trying to update a single item in the form based on a change - by another user on another device - in the value in the back end.  (Firebase in my case.)

I have access to the FormControl and I am able to make that change... except not.  Here's the situation:

[image]

You'll not from the console output, that when I expand the FormGroup and look at the *value* I see 3.  This is the correct value from the back end.  But the `FormGroup.controls.current.value` is still 4... the old value in the form.

I've been trying to play with different methods of accessing this control to get it to update properly.

Here's the code:

```
      this.items.controls.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item.value.current != this.inventoryElements[index].current) {

          //First attempt to change the value of the formControl
          this.items.value[index].current =
            this.inventoryElements[index].current;

          //Second attempt
          this.items.controls[index].value.current =
            this.inventoryElements[index].current;

          //Third attempt
          item.value.current = this.inventoryElements[index].current;

          console.log(this.items.controls[index]);
          console.log(this.items.controls[index].value.current);
          console.log(this.items.value[index].current);
        }
      });
```

`this.inventoryElements[index].current` holds the value I want to put into the form control.
`this.items` is the array of Form Controls.

You can see that I made three attempts to get the value there without luck -

The first `console.log` results in *4*.
The second `console.log` results in *4*.
The third `console.log` results in the output pasted at the top of this question.

One more piece of background.  The FormArray is this `{current: string, notes: string}` and my attempt was to modify the `current` value.

*By the way*, the reason I'm going through all of this mess is that I was unhappy that an update of a single value in the back end would cause the entire page to reload.  So this was an attempt to see whether I could update a single value and avoid the whole page reload.

Thanks the the help.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The third attempt was close.  Instead of assigning the value with an equals sign:

```
item.value.current = this.inventoryElements[index].current;
```

Use `patchValue`

```
item.patchValue({
            current: this.inventoryElements[index].current});
```